# Display posts of a hierarchical custom post type excluding parent posts

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, hierarchical

I am trying to build a query for a hierarchical custom post type and I want to display only parent posts (Exclude Children).

The following is a simple query I added to displaying everything first, but it doesn't work to begin with.

`$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'products',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
 );

$parent = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>

            <?php
                    if(genesis_get_custom_field( 'product_type' ))
                        {
                        echo '<p">' . genesis_get_custom_field( 'product_type' ) . '</p>';
                        } ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?></code>`

Comment: Simply place at least 4 spaces before every line of CODE, then do the proper indentation. Like first block 4 spaces, second block 8 spaces etc. Or, entire code within HTML `<code>` tag. Like:  `<code> //CODE HERE </code>`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However I was able to figure out my problem and I just added the working solution.